# Free energy with two temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

I have struggled to find the free energy F of two individual systems $Z_1, Z_2$ with different temperatures $\beta_1,\beta_2$.

For one common temperature $\beta$, we have

$F =  -\frac{ln(Z_{tot})}{\beta} = -\frac{ln(Z_1(\beta)Z_2(\beta))}{\beta} = -\frac{ln(Z_1(\beta))}{\beta}-\frac{ln(Z_2(\beta))}{\beta}= F_1 + F_2 $

But for two temperatures $Z_{tot} = Z_1(\beta_1)Z_2(\beta_2)$

Should I write

$F = -\frac{ln(Z_1(\beta_1))}{\beta_1}-\frac{ln(Z_2(\beta_2))}{\beta_2}= F_1 + F_2 $

But I cannot have an expression in terms of $Z_{tot}$. Do you have any comment on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free energy is not given as $- \frac{1}{\beta} \ln Z$ in your second situation, because the joint system does not have a unique temperature and is not in thermal equilibrium. The total free energy can only be defined as the sum of the two individual free energies in your second situation, as you did, but one should be careful about this. Usually, thermodynamics assumes that the system under consideration is at a single specific temperature.